# angular 2 full calendar: how to set resources [events]

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, fullcalendar, angular2-template

im facing issue with events->resources in full calendar i have try a lot.
 i have done as per this link [git full calendar](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-fullcalendar). All good i got the view perfectly here all im trying to get resource list at top but getting error
component.ts

```
import { IMyDpOptions, IMyDateModel } from 'mydatepicker';
import * as $ from 'jquery';
import { FullCalendarModule } from 'ng-fullcalendar';
import { CalendarComponent } from 'ng-fullcalendar';
import { Options } from 'fullcalendar';
```

```
export class ClientCalendarComponent implements OnInit {
    calendarOptions: Options;
    @ViewChild(CalendarComponent) ucCalendar: CalendarComponent;
    constructor(private clientCalendarService: ClientCalendarService,
        private route: ActivatedRoute,
        private router: Router) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.calendarOptions = {
            editable: true,
            eventLimit: false,
            header: {
              left: 'prev,next today',
              center: 'title',
              right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay,listMonth'
            },
            defaultView: 'agendaDay',
            resources: [
                {
                    id: 'a',
                    fname: 'John',
                    lname: 'Smith'
                },
                {
                    id: 'b',
                    fname: 'Jerry',
                    lname: 'Garcia'
                }
            ],
            events: [
                {
                    title: 'Click for Google',
                    url: 'http://google.com/',
                    start: '2018-02-18'
                  }
            ]
          };
    }

   }
```

module.ts

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { MyDatePickerModule } from 'mydatepicker';
import { FullCalendarModule } from 'ng-fullcalendar';
```

html code

```
<div *ngIf="calendarOptions">
   <ng-fullcalendar #ucCalendar [options]="calendarOptions" (eventClick)="eventClick($event.detail)" (eventDrop)="updateEvent($event.detail)"
   (eventResize)="updateEvent($event.detail)" (clickButton)="clickButton($event.detail)"></ng-fullcalendar>
 </div>
```

**error**

```
ERROR in /home/mitukula/Desktop/git2/stx-ui/src/app/clientcalendar/clientcalendar.component.ts (40,13): Type '{ editable: true; eventLimit: false; header: { left: string; center: string; right: string; }; de...' is not assignable to type 'Options'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'resources' does not exist in type 'Options'.
```

Comment: im trying to do like this link=> https://fullcalendar.io/docs/vertical_resource_view/groupByDateAndResource/

Comment: you realise you need the FullCalendar Scheduler add-on for this feature, right? You have to pay for it and download it separately. You _may_ be able to get a free license if your organisation (or the client you are working for) meets the criteria. See https://fullcalendar.io/scheduler/